# Jenkins Extended Email Notification - Email Content as attachment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

Using Jenkins 1.499 and version 2.25 of the Jenkins Email Extension Plugin. When emails get sent, the content of the email is showing up as an attachment to the notification and not in the body of the email. In fact, the body of the email is blank. Changing the content type of the email has no effect. We use Exchange/Outlook, could that be the issue? Any ideas to get the content of the email in the body of the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may have to do with your junkmail settings, either in Exchange and/or in Outlook

For me, when I received the first Jenkins email in Outlook, I had to click on the warning lines (just above the email header) and select "Add sender to safe senders list"